# How would I represent this database relation?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

I'm sure that this is basic but I don't know much about database relations.

Example: A Game has Users that each have a Role within the specific Game. Users have different Roles in different Games.
I also need each User to be on a team for each game.

User

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment") private Long id;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) private Date timestamp;
@OneToMany private List<User> players;
@OneToMany private List<Team> teams;
```

Team

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment") private Long id;
@OneToMany private List<User> players;
private int maxSize;
private int type;
```

User
doesn't have any fields except for id and username

I don't understand how I can give Users a role in each game and I don't think I have a good way of including players in teams.
I'm kind of lost about how to represent the relationship, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you need another db table like GameUser?

Comment: I suggest you to make ER diagram using for example ```sql datamodeler``` or just a pen and a piece of paper. You will clearly see relations and relationships between them. ORM will be just a formality

Comment: @bodoroman I decided to go with that. It feels kind of clunky but I guess that's the best you can do with database models.